# Applying container box decoration to button inside it

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout, flutter-android

Can the container box decoration be applied to button inside it. For example I am trying to have circular border in an elevated button. It is not applying in this case.

```
  Container(
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
    ),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15)),
      onPressed: ()  async { navigateToBasketPage(context);
      },
      child: const Text('My basket'),
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks!

Comment: `ElevatedButton.styleFrom(shape: ...`

Answer (score 0):

you can style your button directly. but if you want to apply `Container` border to its child. just add `clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge` property to your `Container`.

Comment: It works. However it also removes the shadow.

Answer (score 0):

To add `decoration` to your **ElevatedButton** you can use `style` property of **ElevatedButton** and and in that property you can apply `decoration` in two ways

**First :**

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(""),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(),
        )
```

**Second :**

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Text(""),
          style: ButtonStyle(),
        )
```

In second method you have to pass values to the fields using **MaterialStatePropety** where in First method you can pass the value in normal way.